# returning a function that doesn't match type alias doesn't produce an error - why?

Tags: typescript

I have the following type alias:

```
type MyDecorator = (target: Function) => Function | void;
```

And I then use it like this:

```
function z(): MyDecorator {
    return function () {

    }
}
```

And it's compiled without an error. Why? I expected to get an error since the function being returned doesn't take any parameters, although one parameter is specified in the type alias.

Comment: This is a FAQ: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters

Comment: @JBNizet, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that it won't throw an error is because the returned function does indeed satisfy `MyDecorator`.

This is because I can do this:

```
z()(() => { console.log("here"); });
```

The fact that the returned function doesn't have a parameter in its signature doesn't mean that it can not receive the param, you can also do this:

```
function z(): MyDecorator {
    return function () {
        let target = arguments[0] as Function;
    }
}
```

You will get an error if you have other params:

```
function z(): MyDecorator {
    return function (a: string) {

    }
}
```

Errors with:

> Type '(a: string) => void' is not assignable to type 'MyDecorator'.
>   Types of parameters 'a' and 'target' are incompatible.
>   Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'string'.